# vb net invoke inside module

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

I'm using vb.net in Visual Studio 2008. I've setup a public sub inside of a module that I'm trying to get multiple threads to be use to update a rich text box.

I would normally be using `ME.INVOKEREQUIRED`....,but it's telling me that "ME" is not valid inside of a module.

Could someone please point me in the right direction here?

Comment: Could we please see your `Module` code please? Seems strange that you're trying to access UI code from a `Module`.

Comment: hey paul if your still watching this, i dont have the code here but im using this function to put updates to what my program is doing in this richtext box, im using 5+ threads and i want each thread to be able to report progress or errors or whats to this text box, which i was hoping to just make one shared sub in a module to handle all of this.

Comment: I think I see what you're after. You probably just need a reference to the Form that you want to get the output in your Module. Still, I would not use the Module for reasons already mentioned but a shared method is ok. Also, there are many, many ways to manage this kind of thing. This is one of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check the `InvokeRequired` property of your `RichTextBox` instance.

Answer (score 2):

That's right. A VB `Module` is a static class and the `Me` keyword does not make sense for it. You need an instance of a `class` to be to use `Me`. It also has to be derived from Control if you're going to cal `InvokeRequired`. You probably need to create and open a `Form` from your module.

Check out this VB article about [Accessing Controls from Worker Threads](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=498387) to get started.

By the way, I'm of the opinion that Modules are a horrible idea and should never be used outside of the application's entry point code. Static classes are useful but the Module is not only static but completely global. i.e. all of its members are globally accessible. This situation can get to be very problematic...